# What does char&* mean?

Tags: c++

This is from the official documentation of AutoCAD 2013 (ObjectARX SDK) from the Autodesk company:

> **ObjectARX for AutoCAD 2013: Readme -> Tips and Techniques -> Freeing**
>   **Strings Returned as Non-const Pointers:**
>
> When calling methods that return non-const string pointers (for
>   example, `AcDbSymbolTable::getName(char&* pName))`, you should free the
>   memory occupied by the returned string. For example:
>
> ```
> // The getName() call should be followed by a call to
> acutDelString(pLtName);pLtTableRcd->getName(pLtName);
> // ... other code
> acutDelString(pLtName);
> ```
>
> Note that some of the ObjectARX sample files are missing calls to free
>   the memory, so they will exhibit memory leaks. When using the samples
>   in your own code, make sure to free the memory properly.

What does the next argument type mean:

```
AcDbSymbolTable::getName(char&* pName))
```

Is it pointer to `char&`? In what sense? When is such a construct used?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) `pName` is a pointer to a reference to a `char`.

I would say that it doesn't make much sense in having a pointer to a reference. The other way around (having a reference to a pointer) can be useful though, as you can then change the pointer inside the function.

Comment: It doesn't just not make sense, it is forbidden by the standard, see [dcl.ref]/5 _"There shall be no references to references, no references to arrays of runtime bound, no arrays of references,
and no pointers to references."_

Comment: I didn't invent this example. This is from the official documentation of AutoCAD from the Autodesk company.

Comment: @Bush In that case I think it's most probably a typo, and they really mean `AcDbSymbolTable::getName(char*& pName)` (note that `&` and `*` are reversed).

Comment: The thing is, not only `T&*` is explicitly forbidden by the standard, but you can't even produce one. If you have a `T&` and try to take its address you'll end up with the address of the referenced object, not of the reference object (ie. you'll get a `T*` not a `T&*`). So @Joachim is probably right, this might be a typo in the documentation. That, or they are using an awfully ancient, non-standard compiler (which I doubt).

Comment: I checked the original again. No, I wasn't mistaken.

Comment: @Bush You're not mistaken in what you read, but it could still be a simple typo in the documentation. (See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17484856/1600898) for details.) Either way, the header file is the authoritative source.

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo in the documentation; what they mean is `AcDbSymbolTable::getName(char*& pName))`.

If you read it like that, the rest of the paragraph makes perfect sense: `getName` is a function that retrieves a string (`char *`) via an out-parameter declared as a reference to string. It even goes on to say that the returned "string" must be freed using `acutDelString`.

If you take a look at the actual declaration in the header file, you will most likely find the parameter declared as `char*&`.